# What is the best practice for caching Solr search results with Varnish?

Tags: wordpress, solr, varnish

Working with a WordPress site where we replaced the search function with Solr. Solr returns the search results and we make certain wp queries, it would make sense to cache the most frequent searches.

What is the best practice regarding the caching of search results? Dos and dont's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr does provide Out of Box caching ability for the frequent searches and filter searches which makes the Response more performant.
Refer to the [Solr Caching](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching) to check the behavior and configuration.
You would need to fine tune the Configurations so have more hits to make use of the cache effectively.